# Property 'save' is missing in type 'typeof ExampleService' but required in type 'ExampleAbstractClassService'

Tags: angular, service, interface

I have a service named 'ExampleService' and I am trying to create interface for the same with the name 'ExampleAbstractClassService'. I followed the [blog](https://medium.com/hackernoon/creating-interfaces-for-angular-services-1bb41fbbe47c#:%7E:text=I%20mentioned%20above%20that%20Angular,to%20use%20an%20abstract%20class).

So my code is as follows:

ExampleService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ExampleAbstractClassService } from 'example';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
 export class ExampleService implements ExampleAbstractClassService {
  save() {
   throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
}
```

ExampleAbstractClassService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export abstract class ExampleAbstractClassService {
  abstract save();
}
```

Now I am defining the service instance in config.module as:
example.config.ts, I want to pass the existing service instance instead of passing "new Service".

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ExampleAbstractClassService } from './example-abstract-class.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ExampleConfig {
  serviceInstance?: ExampleAbstractClassService;
}
```

And using it in app.module as:

```
ExampleModule.forRoot({
  serviceInstance: ExampleService
})
```

But on compiling, I am getting following error:

```
ERROR in app.module.ts:28:24 - error TS2741: Property 'save' is missing in type 'typeof ExampleService' but required in type 'ExampleAbstractClassService'.

28       serviceInstance: ExampleService
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/some-project/example/example-abstract-class.service.d.ts:3:14
    3     abstract save(): any;
                   ~~~~
    'save' is declared here.
  app.module.ts:28:24
    28       serviceInstance: ExampleService
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Did you mean to use 'new' with this expression?
```

Comment: Error says:  "Did you mean to use 'new' with this expression?" you use the Class as a value
 -> serviceInstance: new ExampleService()

Comment: No i want to use the extising service instance instead of new ExampleService()

Comment: yes but your not doing that. you just add the class Definition into it. Which is why the compiler complains. You either have to get an instance and pass it or create a new one. Or alter the type to expect providers as an input: https://angular.io/api/core/ModuleWithProviders

Comment: @Krosan thanks..i will try that and get back to you